# How can I invoke a user switch from the command line?

Tags: command-line, 12.04, session, unity-greeter, switch-user

In 11.10 I used 'gdmflexiserver -xnest' to switch users without logging out however I think gdm has now been completely removed.

I'm trying to bind a keyboard shortcut to do the equivalent of 'Me Menu>Switch User Account...'.

How can I invoke a user switch in 12.04?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`gdmflexiserver` as a legacy option to provide the greeter switcher service during the transition between GDM and LightDM.

This has now been dropped from 12.04.

The replacement command is:

```
dm-tool switch-to-greeter
```

Other useful `dm-tool` options (`dm-tool --help`):

[image]

Comment: unlike the me menu `dm-tool swich-to-greeter` doesn't lock session you just left.

Comment: On ubuntu 16.04 `dm-tool swich-to-greeter` *does* lock session you just left.

Comment: If like us you want to switch without typing password every time, consider this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/811953/switching-between-two-opened-x-sessions-without-reauthenticating

Comment: it doesn't _log out_ the session you just left :P

Comment: Does not work in 17.10 anymore. Maybe because ubuntu now uses GDM?

Comment: @Matmarbon correct - as the answer mentions - this works for LightDM only.

Comment: @Matmarbon Xubuntu 18.04 uses lightdm and you can, too. Canonical [continues support for lightdm and it might even be the default again for Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1004461/is-gdm3-preferred-to-lightdm).

Answer (score -1):

You can have several users logged in at the same time and switch between them with alt+ctrl+F1-8. That doesn't allow you to have another x server in a window. By the way; GDM has not been removed. It's just not used by default. You can easily install it: http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gdm.

Comment: I really dont think that is what the user is asking here.

Comment: My fault, I updated the question to make it clearer what Im trying to achieve. I know GDM is still available but most of the functionality is being moved to lightDM. In 11.10, the GDM command 'gdmflexiserver -xnest' would start another x server using the LightDM protocol allowing a user to log in using the GUI. But now GDM is not installed by default so there must be a replacement command that does the same but is lightdm native.

Comment: You can use ctrl+alt+F7 and ctrl+alt+F8 to switch between two logged in users when they are already logged in.