# Switch user shortcut in Gnome Shell UI?

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, gnome, shortcut-keys

I cannot seem to find a default switch-user shortcut in Gnome Shell. Does such exist?

If not, how can I make the one? I mean, I know that I should go to Keyboard Shortcuts tool (Custom shortcuts tab), but I do not which shell command to use. Which shell command is used to activate switch user?

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

What you are after is available as an extension at https://extensions.gnome.org

Called the *Alternative Status Menu* - this gives you the switch-user capability.

However - if you really want a keyboard shortcut then search for *keyboard* and add a new short cut with either `gdmflexiserver` in 11.10 or `dm-tool switch-to-greeter` as the command together with the keyboard shortcut itself:

[image]

This is described further in this Q&A:
 - [How can I invoke a user switch from the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/111116/how-can-i-invoke-a-user-switch-from-the-command-line/111810#111810)