# Running XScreenSaver on ubuntu 18.04, how can I return to user login lockscreen instead of XScreenSaver lockscreen (so we can switch users)?

Tags: login, lock-screen, screensaver

Running XScreenSaver V5.36 on Ubuntu 18.04 with multiple users with different login sessions. When XscreenSaver launches from one user session, only that user can come back to the computer. We are locked in the user's session from which XScreenSaver went to lockscreen.

How can I return to the default initial Ubuntu (the one at startup) user login lockscreen instead of XScreenSaver lockscreen (so we can switch users)?

Most of the documentation and threads on the XScreenSaver subject never mentions multiple users issues.

Answer (score 0):

The XScreenSaver locks the screen inside your user session, in which you logged in.
So there is no chance to get out of your X-Session from the XScreensaver.
When you log out, a "GDM" (Graphical Display Manager) takes over and resets the X-Session. 
You could start more than one X-Session, but changing to another from within the XScreensaver will not be possible. 
You might look at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/811953/switching-between-two-opened-x-sessions-without-reauthenticating) how to change between 2 opened X-Sessions.